# Are bosses usually in the same location during a challenge?

Tags: tokyo-jungle

I'm trying to unlock the Golden Retriever animal class as the Beagle.  However, I'm having a really hard time trying to find the boss animal to unlock.  I'm in the correct district, I have looked all over the area, but I just cannot find him.

Comment: Do you want to know where the boss is, or just whether or not its location can change from game to game?

Comment: I guess the former. After a second run through, the district he was in was different. However, once I'm in the district, will the boss wander or stay to a specific are in the district?